# Toolbar not showing

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I have created an interface using interface builder with a tabBarController. This tabBar controller has three viewControllers. There is a problem with the last one, that displays an image View and a toolBar on top of the screen. The toolbar contains two buttons and a label. Sometimes, when there is an image, it doesn't appear.Any idea why ?

Here are some snapshots:

[image: when the toolbar appears]
[image: when the toolbar doesn't appear]

[image: View in Interface Builder]

After the change Douglas advised me:

[image]

Comment: Any progress?  Let us know, would love to see how things turned out for future reference.

Comment: I finally resolved this problem by replacing the label on the top (here showing Plaine de Plainpalais) by a tabBarItem and by resizing the UIView (now it's not under the tab and the toolbar). Thank you for your interest in this matter

Answer (score 0):

You may have a restraint between the imageview and the toolbar so that when the image view is displayed it pushes the toolbar up to high and you can't see it. I would check the restraints and adjust.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I have thought of that but even when i make my UIimage view small, the toolbar doesn't (always) show up.

Comment: I tried to replicate what you did, but my toolbar always shows.  Are you sure that you placed it fully inside the view?  Or did you place it in its own uiview?

Comment: Click on the toolbar, then go to the menu at the top and select editor(I'm pretty sure it's called editor, not at my comp right now) and select arrange.  Make sure the tab bar is not being covered by any other view by sending to front.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now the problem has slightly changed! I will upload a new image ..

Comment: In the storyboard pane have you maybe selected the iPhone 5 size, and running the sim in iPhone 4 mode?  There is a small toggle switch next to the align and pin buttons. Try that.